# Add object to laravel collection at a specified location

Tags: laravel, collections

I want to add a new object to a laravel collection in some specified location, can anyone help me achieve this ?

for example:

```
“data”: [
 {
  “provider”: ‘datechanged’,
  “unogsdate”: “2019-01-25",
  “download”: 3
 }
 {
   “id”: 54946,
   “provider”: “netflix”,
   “netflixid”: 80171173,
   “unogsdate”: “2019-01-25”,
 }{
   “id”: 54946,
   “provider”: “netflix”,
   “netflixid”: 80171173,
   “unogsdate”: “2019-01-25”,
 }{
   “id”: 54946,
   “provider”: “netflix”,
   “netflixid”: 80171173,
   “unogsdate”: “2019-01-25”,
 }
 {
  “provider”: ‘datechanged’,
  “unogsdate”: “2019-01-27",
  “download”: 5
 }
 {
   “id”: 54946,
   “provider”: “netflix”,
   “netflixid”: 80171173,
   “unogsdate”: “2019-01-27”,
 }{
   “id”: 54946,
   “provider”: “netflix”,
   “netflixid”: 80171173,
   “unogsdate”: “2019-01-27”,
 }{
   “id”: 54946,
   “provider”: “netflix”,
   “netflixid”: 80171173,
   “unogsdate”: “2019-01-27”,
 }{
   “id”: 54946,
   “provider”: “netflix”,
   “netflixid”: 80171173,
   “unogsdate”: “2019-01-27”,
 }{
   “id”: 54946,
   “provider”: “netflix”,
   “netflixid”: 80171173,
   “unogsdate”: “2019-01-27”,
 }
```

I want to add a new record exactly before the starting of new date based on record, for example just before date unogsdate: 2019-01-25 started, i want to add a new record with 
{
  “provider”: ‘datechanged’,
  “unogsdate”: “2019-01-25",
  “download”: 3
 }
just as shown in below example....any help will be much apprecitaed.

Comment: How is this collection produced? Could you share some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: It's a record fetched from database and paginated at last. Let me share you my code
<pre>
$videos =  Video::where('country','=',$request->country)
                            ->select('netflixid', 'title', 'image', 'image_height', 'image_width', 'released', 'rating', 'type', 'unogsdate', 'genre', 'imdbid', 'runtime')
                            ->where('unogsdate','>=',$date)
                            ->orderby('unogsdate','DESC')
                            ->paginate($perPage);
            }
</pre>

Comment: In your particular case, the [prepend()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-prepend) method is what you are looking for, but I don't have enough information as to how it should be applied.

Comment: yes, prepend appends to begining, but i need to add at specified index, because as per example once date change is detected we need to add a new record just above the record where date change takes place.

Comment: Are you wanting the collection to be ordered by date?

Comment: no not date, if you see the example result i have posted, it has a new record appended just above when unogsdate changes...so in loop whenever a unogsdate change is found we just need to append a new record just above it with the new parameters such as datechanged, count, unogsdate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this entirely with the methods available in Laravel [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections).

Here's how I'd do it:

1. I would group the data by their dates. In your case `unogsdate`.
2. I will then loop over the collection with `each()`
3. That would allow me to `prepend()` the sub-collection with the data I need.
4. Finally, I would `flatten()` the collection.

Here's an example:

```
$collection = collect([
    (object) [
        'id' => 54946,
        'provider' => 'netflix',
        'netflixid' => 80171173,
        'unogsdate' => '2019-01-25'
    ],
    (object) [
        'id' => 54946,
        'provider' => 'netflix',
        'netflixid' => 80171173,
        'unogsdate' => '2019-01-25'
    ],
    (object) [
        'id' => 54946,
        'provider' => 'netflix',
        'netflixid' => 80171173,
        'unogsdate' => '2019-01-25'
    ],

    (object) [
        'id' => 54946,
        'provider' => 'netflix',
        'netflixid' => 80171173,
        'unogsdate' => '2019-01-27'
    ],

    (object) [
        'id' => 54946,
        'provider' => 'netflix',
        'netflixid' => 80171173,
        'unogsdate' => '2019-01-27'
    ]
]);

return $collection->groupBy('unogsdate')
    ->each(function($value, $key) {
        return $value->prepend(
            (object) [
                'provider' => 'datechanged',
                'unogsdate' => $key,
                'downloads' => $value->count()
            ]
        );
    })
    ->flatten();
```

Of course, I have no idea how you are getting the actual data. However, the collection above resembles your current dataset. You can easily re-apply this to your Collection.

Also, here's a [working example](https://implode.io/uHGCeH) you can play with :)

Comment: thanks a lot @Mozammil......that worked like a charm.....i was trying with foreach by comparing the dates and counting them and appending new records.....damn i was thinking the long way.....thanks a lot man.